# YAML Coverity Configuration for C custom compiler not analyzing C files

Tags: c, coverity

I'm currently working on a C project with a custom compiler. I'm able to build everything with coverity scan -c myyaml.yml but at the end I always end with 1 python file analyzed and a warning message at the end of my build. At the end only want all the .c/.h files to be analyzed :

```
[WARNING] No files were emitted. This may be due to a problem with your configuration
or because no files were actually compiled by your build command.
Please make sure you have configured the compilers actually used in the compilation.

Files analyzed                       : 1 Total
    Python 3                         : 1
```

Below is my yaml configuration :

```
capture:
  compiler-configuration:
    cov-configure:
    - [ --template, --compiler, custom_compiler, --comptype, gcc]

  build:
    clean-command: 'make-dsp clean && make-dsp tree'
    build-command: 'make-dsp build'
analyze:
  aggressiveness-level: medium
  c-cpp-virtual: true
  c-cpp-fnptr: true
  coding-standards:
    misrac2012:
      pre-canned: required-advisory
  checkers:
    all: true
    rule: true
    c-family-security: true
    checker-config:
      INFINITE_LOOP:
        enabled: true
        options:
          report_no_escape: true
  parse-warnings:
    enabled: true
  trust:
    all: false

commit:
  # Specifies where the analysis results should be sent.
  connect:
    on-new-cert: trust
    auth-key-file: totokey.txt
    stream: totoproject
    url: totototo
    description: 'Analysis executed by Jenkins'
```